# Show results of Jupyterlab on Tkinter UI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am currently working on building an UI to show the images in my JupyterLab to my Tkinter UI, that is running on a same script. In my script, I hope that after entering the values in Tkinter, it will take in the input and run again, and show the image on Tkinter UI again, so that I can do try and error. Can anyone guide me or give me a little tips to know where to find the answer and how to work on it?

```
from tk import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import tkinter as tk
import os
window = tk.Tk()

def show_result(a,b,c,d):
    #display the image result
    #run the again to test the result
    
x1 = tk.IntVar()
x2 = tk.IntVar()
y1 = tk.IntVar()
y2 = tk.IntVar()

# set textbox to capture variables 
x1_value = ttk.Entry(textvariable=x1).place(x=50, y=50)
x2_value = ttk.Entry(textvariable=x2).place(x=50, y=100)
y1_value = ttk.Entry(textvariable=y1).place(x=50, y=150)
y2_value = ttk.Entry(textvariable=y2).place(x=50, y=200)
    
display_button = ttk.Button(text="Run", command= lambda: show_result(x1.get(),x2.get(),y1.get(),y2.get())).place(x=50, y=300)

window.geometry("900x750")
window.mainloop( )
```

Comment: You can use `matplotlib` to display graphs in a local Tkinter GUI. You shouldn't be using Juptyer with Tkinter

Comment: @OneCricketeer that is a request from my boss. I need to display the image produced by matplotlib on Tkinter

Comment: Okay, and what have you tried to this affect? Matplotib can save png files to disk, or BytesIO object, then Tkinter should be able to render those in a canvas. Also see https://ishantheperson.github.io/posts/tkinter-matplotlib/

Comment: I have solved it by saving the image with matplotlib savefig, and load it on Tkinter UI.

Comment: Feel free to add your complete answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
plt.figure(figsize = (50,8))
plt.imshow(crop_img, cmap='gray')
fig1 = plt.gcf()
fig1.savefig('crop_img.png', dpi=100)
open_img()
```

---

```
# Open img to show on tkinter 
def open_img():
    x = 'crop_img.png'
    img = Image.open(x)
    left=2000
    top=0
    right=3000
    bottom=800
    img = img.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
    img = img.resize((800, 600), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    panel = Label(window, image=img)
    panel.image = img
    panel.place(x=200, y=0)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).